# SSL for private network

Tags: tls, network, openssl, server

I have a private network, a VPS, an Apache web server and several web pages.

Most documentation about SSL configuration state that I should buy a certificate, and should give the website adress.
However, in my case, it's a private network, none of the pages are seen in the global network.

May I somehow configure SSL for the webpages in my VPS, to connect to the pages via https?

**UPDATE**

Actually, there are several websites which describe what I want to do. The real problem is that, when I create certificates myself, the webpage everytime says that the certificate is not verified. May I somehow solve this? To buy a certificate is not an option

Comment: You have to make yourself a CA, add its cert in your trust store and then all certs issued by it will appear as trusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that need to be done in order for you to serve your private networked sites over HTTPS.

1. You need to setup an OpenSSL based certificate authority.  I don't have a link handy, but you can google it and I am sure you will find what you are looking for.
2. You need to generate a CSR - certificate signing request which basically provides the details around the site that you are trying to protect with HTTPS, eg the common name, which is the actual URL.
3. You need to generate a certificate singed by the certificate authority that you created in step# 1.
4. You will then adjust your web sever or application server to use the SSL certificate and the certificate authority certificate that you created. You should be able to figure the steps for this via a Google query.
5. Once the certificate is setup on the server, you need to install the certificate authority certificate in your browser. There are a bunch of steps for each of the browsers, Google can help with locating the exact steps.

Once the certificate authority certificate is installed on your client machine's browser, when you visit the URL of your site, using the common name that you provided while setting up the certificate, you should not see a warning, but a green HTTPS padlock in the browser address bar, confirming that the certificate is trustworthy.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for a publicly trusted certificate from letsencrypt: https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the CA is not in your trusted certificate store

Comment: OK, How to add it?